# How to stretch list text to fill webpage

Tags: html, css, frontend

[my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgUz6.png)

In the link above I have a list where I specify cities of service, and right now the list seems to be condensed. I tried to stretch it out using the font-stretch function using in-line CSS but it doesn't seem to be working. Are there any other ideas anyone has?

```
<style>
  h2 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size:50px;
}
h3{
  font-size:45px;
  
}
li{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-stretch: 100%;
}
</style>
<h1 style='text-align:center' class='tjs-h2'></h1>

<div class="maps container-fluid" style="align-items: center; background: #F3F3F3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h2 class="font-2">Serving the Greater Twin Cities Area </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-12 d-flex justify-content-center pb-4">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d90327.44687139073!2d-93.2367809086671!3d44.96942454616932!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x87f629fd5bb7538f%3A0xd070c186a8aea420!2sTwin%20Cities%2C%20MN!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1639701112792!5m2!1sen!2sus" width="600" height="600" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy">
                </iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
              <h3>
                <ul class="cities">
                    <li >Minneapolis and suburbs 10 minutes in any direction</li>
                    <li >St. Paul and suburbs 10 minutes in any direction</li>
                </ul>
              </h3>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-

    </div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Are yo using Bootstrap? If so, label it correctly with the correct version. Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 0):

You could widen the div instead. I tried out the code on my computer. The website displayed a bit differently, but this seemed to help.

`div#navigation {width: XXXpx; }`

`<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" id="navigation">`